# Word for Mac won't take pasted hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink

I've inserted hyperlinks into a Word document (on Mac) for years by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> and pasting in the buffer from <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and suddenly it stopped working.

Same problem seems to exist pasting in the buffer to an excel cmd-F find query.

¿Ideas to make it work again ... or explanations as to why this is happening would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: If you want to help, please post your answer as a separate answer and not a part of your question.

Comment: Ditto. [You can answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer), but your answer (like anyone else's answer here) should be an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> the hyperlink insertion menu will accept <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the buffer. I am not sure why, perhaps that key stroke routine has been corrupted. But it is a viable work-around.

It also seems to work on the occasional paste into excel find function.